# fail to start a service through setComponent or action and setPackage

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not start a service through setComponent or action and setPackage, eg:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("io.github.grooters.practicer.BindeRer","io.github.grooters.practicer.BindeRer.ServicerTest"));
    startService(intent);

    Intent intent=new Intent("io.github.grooters.practicer.BindeRer.ServicerTest");
    intent.setPackage("io.github.grooters.practicer.BindeRer");
    startService(intent);
```

but i can start through startService(this,ServicerTest.class)

Comment: Have you added your service class in manifest?

Comment: I am sure I have added

Comment: upload your manifest code...

Comment: <service android:name=".BindeRer.ServicerTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="io.github.grooters.practicer.BindeRer.ServicerTest"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>